# what means by using 'new' to create a temp object?

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, new-operator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Place{
private:
    int park;
    int num;
public:
Place() { park=1; num=1;};
}

int main{
Place* pool = new Place;
delete pool;
}
```

So for this part of code `Place* pool = new Place;`, I believe that default constructor will be called and it means that the object `pool` now also be created and is pointing to a temp object with `Place` class. But exactly what does it mean? It means that the `pool` object is pointing to the whole temp object or does it mean that each data member in the `pool` object is pointing to the data member in the temp object respectively?

Also, when `Place* pool = new Place;` is called, is that both of the temp object and the `pool` is initialized by the default constructor? Or only the temp object is initialized by the default constructor? I feel so lost when studying the OOP topics and topics related to the constructor and destructor. I hope that I do not ask a stupid question. Thanks so much for all of your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "temp object"? `new Place;` dynamically allocates an object of type `Place` and calls its default constructor (and returns a pointer to it). It's also completely unnecessary in this code snippet, `Place pool;` would work fine (if not better)

Comment: There is no temporary object. And if you create it manually by new, don't forget to destroy by delete. And please write correct constructors. Your int values we be initialized by 0 and overwritten by 1 later in the constructor body. OK, the compiler will optimize this away in this special case. But formally it is not what you expect!

Comment: i just want to know what is the meaning of this line of code. As ```Place* pool = new Place;``` appears in my assignment. But I do not quite understand how the new operator works with the object type.

Comment: it's `new expression` here and you had to look up that term instead of `operator new`, if that's where confusion comes from.

Comment: Google is your friend. In short, it means memory (large enough for Place's members) is allocated on the heap, the address is assigned to pool, and the constructor is called to initialize the memory (the last two not necessarily in that order). Unless you call delete, the memory will not be released until the program terminates.

Comment: So what is exactly the type of the pointer ```pool```? As there is ```Place*``` in front of the ```pool```, so I am confused about what exactly this type is. So does it means that the ```pool``` pointer could only point to class type ```Place```?

Answer (score 3):

For starters there are several typos.

For example you wrote a parenthesis instead of the closing brace

```
Place() { park=1; num=1;)
                       ^^^
```

And you forgot to place a semicolon after the class definition.

`pool` is a pointer. Pointers are designed to store addresses. `pool` is not an object of the type `Place`. This pointer points to an object of the type `Place` that was dynamically allocated. Using the pointer you may access public members of the pointed object.
To make it clear you could split this declaration

```
Place* pool = new Place;
```

into these statements

```
Place* pool = nullptr;
pool = new Place;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have corrected it. So what is the type of the pointer ```pool```? Is that class type Place?

Comment: @ttt23  The type of the pointer is seen from its declaration Place *. What is the problem?!

Comment: so pointer ```pool``` is just a pointer without any data member. And what it is pointing at is the allocated memory that are initialized by the constructor?

Comment: @ttt23 Pointers are fundamental scalar objects. They are not user-defined objects. So neither constructor is called when a pointer is declared. In the presented program the pointer will point to the dynamically allocated object with using the operator new.